# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKEditor/CKFinder as wysiwyg editor on my MVC.NET site.

I have set `[ValidateInput(false)]` and it works when debugging it locally, but I receive the following error when I have published the site:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (message="<p>
<em>Testing</e...").
```

can anyone explain why the published site is different from the locally site, especially when I have set `[ValidateInput(false)]`?

**Update:**I am using .Net 3.5 so shouldn't  `[ValidateInput(false)]` work out the box?

Comment: Adding the web.config won't disable the validation on all pages unless you specify `[ValidateInput(false)]` before action.

Comment: Can you confirm that the .NET AppPool which your published site is using is not running under .NET 4.0? I am guessing it is.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the hos ran .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I didn't want to disable it on all pages. Also my question was also about why it was different when debugging than when published.

Comment: this won't turn it of for all pages. It will just make your attribute [ValidateInput(false)] work. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: I am using MVC.Net 3.5 so shouldn't [ValidateInput(false)] work out of the box?

Comment: requestValidationMode is as far as I know not an attribute in the .Net 3.5

Comment: The answer was to have the host change the App pool to .Net 3.5, but since this answer would have helped if i was running .net 4.0 I am marking it as the answer.

Comment: This fixes the reported error, but removes request validation from your whole website, I don't think this should be the Accepted answer.

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried setting the htmlEncodeOutput property?

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    htmlEncodeOutput: true });
```

This should encode the output and you should be able to avoid setting the requestValidationMode.

Documentation for it is here: [ckEditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.htmlEncodeOutput)

Comment: +1 this is better than disabling the validation in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with @ashes999. Two indications to help future readers of the post **1** 'editor1' is the id of the ckeditor control **2** don't forget to decode the value received after POST with _System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode_ otherwise you'll probably continue to have same error.

Comment: I am not use CKEDITOR.replace(), I use <textarea class="ckeditor" ..., what should I do?

Comment: And then use 
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Text))</textarea> 
to decode encoded text from database, when you need to edit the text. Se more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978281/html-encode-decode-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Just add an Annotation to the Post method Action as [ValidateInput(false)]

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Detail(ModelClass m)
    { return View(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

ValidateRequest="false"
Add this in the particular Page.

Example:

Answer (score 0):

Add `ValidateRequest="false"` to your Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="MyForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Proj.MyForm" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

Or add to web.config if using .NET Framework 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010)

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request.Unvalidated["myTextBox"]`

for example,

```
var text = Request.Unvalidated["myTextBox"];
```

where "myTextBox" is the form field you want to allow HTML to be posted from.